# Why can't the determinant of a rotation matrix be $-1$?

Tags: matrices, determinant, rotations

I proved that the determinant of a rotational matrix(which represents a rotation in 3D) must be $+1$ or $-1$, but I am not sure why it can't be $-1$.

I proved it using the fact that the Matrix must be orthogonal, therefore the determinant squared must be $1$.

Comment: What does determinant mean to you, geometrically?

Comment: What is your definition of rotation matrix? The determinant of $$\left( \begin{matrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{matrix} \right)$$ is clearly $+1$

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I saw that article, but it only mention about in two dimension

Comment: @Arthur the scalar of change in volume?

Comment: @projectilemotion the Matrix need to be orthogonal, and the determinant squared must be 1

Comment: @Crostul what about the Matrix in 3D that is not of this form?

Comment: It is a matter of direction. If +1 is counterclockwise, -1 clockwise.

Comment: @farruhota is counterclockwise -1?

Comment: in any dimension, rotations do not change orientation, and this implies the claim.

Comment: @farruhota No, direction of the rotation itself is not related to the determinant, or even well-defined since a counterclockwise rotation by $\theta$ is the same as a clockwise rotation by $-\theta$.

Comment: @anon, you are right, sorry, it is $\begin{vmatrix} \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \\ \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} \cos{(-\theta)} & -\sin{(-\theta)} \\ \sin{(-\theta)} & \cos{(-\theta)} \\ \end{vmatrix}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a rotation "in time". Let $T$ be the rotation by some angle $\phi>0$ around the axis  ${\bf a}$. Then there is a continuous map
$$f:\quad[0,\phi]\to O(3),\qquad t\mapsto A(t)$$
with $A(0)={\rm id}$ and $A(\phi)=T$, namely $A(t)$ is the rotation by the angle $t$ around ${\bf a}$. Since ${\rm det}\bigl(A(0)\bigr)=1$ and the determinant is a continuous function on the space of linear maps it follows that ${\rm det}(T)={\rm det}\bigl(A(\phi)\bigr)=1$.

Comment: Why there is such continuous $f$?

Comment: What is $O(3)$?

Comment: @IntegrateThis: The group of orthogonal $3\times3$-matrices.